# Marionette Collection View - not rendering the collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

My collection view not rendering properly, instead it throw the error...

here is my code :

```
var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();

        ContactManager.addRegions({
            content : "#main-region"
        })

        ContactManager.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend();

        ContactManager.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : ContactManager.Contact
        })

        ContactManager.ContactView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: "#contact-list-item"
        });


        ContactManager.on("start", function () {

            var contacts = new ContactManager.Collection([
                {
                    firstName: "Bob",
                    lastName: "Brigham",
                    phoneNumber: "555-"
                },
                {
                    firstName: "Alice",
                    lastName: "Arten",
                    phoneNumber: "555-0184"
                },
                {
                    firstName: "Charlie",
                    lastName: "Campbell",
                    phoneNumber: "555-0129"
                }
            ]);

            ContactManager.content.show(Marionette.CollectionView.extend({ //nothing renders here
                tagName: "ul",
                childView : ContactManager.ContactView,
                collection : contacts
            }));
        })
        ContactManager.start();
```

All my `templates` are there in `DOM` and I am getting an error as :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

any one help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing one thing, and that's when you're calling `show` on your content region you need to pass an instance of your collection view.

Marionette is throwing an error when it tries to bind events to your uninstantiated view.

```
ContactManager.ContactCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({ //nothing renders here
  tagName: "ul",
  childView : ContactManager.ContactView,
  collection : contacts
});

ContactManager.content.show(new ContactManager.ContactCollectionView());
```